# Split month by week range (Monday-Friday) in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, monthcalendar

I'm using SQL Server 2008R2 and I'm trying to split given month by week ranges. I got the following solution. But, I want days between (Mon-Fri) not (Sun-Sat). How can I do this?

```
DECLARE @start_date DATETIME, @end_date DATETIME
DECLARE @Table table(StartDate datetime,Enddate datetime,WeekNo int)

SET @start_date = '1 Dec 2018'
SET @end_date =   '31 Dec 2018'

INSERT @Table 
SELECT MIN(dt), MAX(dt), w
FROM
(
    SELECT dt, year(dt) y, DATEPART(week,dt) w
    FROM
    (
        SELECT @start_date + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1) dt
        FROM sys.columns s1 cross join sys.columns s2
    ) q
    WHERE dt BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
) a
group by y,w

Select * from @Table order by startdate, weekno
```

Comment: If 1-Dec-2018 is not a monday then you want the nearest monday to the start_date?. and if 31-Dec is not a friday do you want it the last friday up til 31-Dec-2018

Comment: @george-joseph if that is possible, it'll be great. otherwise a regular week ranges is also okay for me. (i.e. 31-Dec-2018 to 4-Jan-2019) in this month end case

Comment: the weekno in your query would be computed on the basis of the iso week definition itself isnt it?

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph Yes. How to get regular week ranges  (i.e. 31-Dec-2018 to 4-Jan-2019) in this month end case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to generate only records and gets the monday dates between @start_date and @end_date

After that ensure the boundary conditions are taken into account for

```
DECLARE @start_date DATETIME, @end_date DATETIME
DECLARE @Table table(StartDate datetime,Enddate datetime,WeekNo int)

SET @start_date = '1 Nov 2018'
SET @end_date =   '30 Nov 2018'

set datefirst 1;

INSERT @Table 
     SELECT dt as start_of_week
           ,dateadd(dd,4,dt) as end_of_week
           ,DATEPART(week,dt) w
           ,datepart(dw,q.dt)
      FROM
      (
        SELECT @start_date + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1) dt              
          FROM sys.columns s1 cross join sys.columns s2
       ) q
    WHERE dt BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
     AND datepart(dw,q.dt)=1 /*Gets only the days beginning from monday*/
     --AND dateadd(dd,4,q.dt) <= @end_date /*Ignore any records which cross over the @end_date*/

Select * from @Table order by startdate, weekno
```

Comment: How to get regular week ranges (i.e. 31-Dec-2018 to 4-Jan-2019) in this month end case

Comment: Just get rid of the last condition -- AND dateadd(dd,4,dt) <= @end_date /*Ignore any records which cross over the @end_date*/

Comment: No, If I do that, it'll take Mon-Sun. How to get  (31-Dec-2018 to 4-Jan-2019)

Comment: In case of November 2018, It starts from 5th Nov 2018 instead of Oct 29. (regular week)

Comment: Learnt something new today->set datefirst. i have updated the code to set datefirst 1. You can see the results for 1-Nov-2018 now